# I want to save the photo with an extension

Tags: c#

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    
    string picname = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + patch.GetExtension(FileUpload_pic.FileName);
    string serverpatch = Server.MapPath("~/img/");
    FileUpload_pic.SaveAs(serverpatch + picname );

}
```

I want to save the photo with an extension.

Comment: So what's stopping you? "I want" isn't a question, and you provide no explanation as to why what you have isn't working. I've also removed the other tags, as I don't see anything in the above related to SQL Server or ASP.Net.

Comment: In the picture, it is clear that the second line has the phrase Get Extension.

Comment: The image was just a duplication of your code fence; it didn't add anything to the question and so I removed it. it was not helpful as you should [not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    
    string picname = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +(FileUpload_pic.FileName);
    string serverpatch = Server.MapPath("~/img/");
    FileUpload_pic.SaveAs(serverpatch + picname );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment pointing to **`patch.GetExtension`** it seems like you're looking for a method to get the extension of a file name.

Here it is:

[Path.GetExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-6.0).